# Binary downloads with minicom get truncated

Tags: linux, buffering

I'm using minicom on Linux to talk to a PDP-11 and I'm using the shell script described [here](http://www.dannysung.com/wmain/linux/tips/sending-binary-files-via-minicom/) to download binaries.  What I'm seeing is the progress bar shown by 'pv' shows the download is taking place nearly instantly rather than at the 9600 bps the serial line runs at (it's a real serial port on the Linux end, not a USB serial dongle).

It works but as the download gets larger, the end gets chopped off.  If I increase the sleep() time at the end of the script, I can get it to work again.

It appears to me that the output is being buffered in the kernel and if the script (not the pv program, oddly) exits too soon then the buffer is flushed.

I tried writing my own little C program in place of the shell script and pv, thinking that by using setvbuf() to set _IONBF I could fix this. Same results.

Any ideas on how I can get this buffering turned off, either in pv or by writing my own program?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Investigating the sources for minicom shows that it does flush the buffer when the sub-program returns so having that program wait is necessary.

I never found a way to turn off the buffering but I did find the tcdrain() function that allows my program to wait until the data is transmitted before exiting.